# How can I create/process variables in a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, variables, loops, cell-array

I need to calculate the mean, standard deviation, and other values for a number of variables and I was wondering how to use a loop to my advantage. I have 5 electrodes of data. So to calculate the mean of each I do this:

```
mean_ch1 = mean(ch1);  
mean_ch2 = mean(ch2);  
mean_ch3 = mean(ch3);  
mean_ch4 = mean(ch4);  
mean_ch5 = mean(ch5);
```

What I want is to be able to condense that code into a line or so. The code I tried does not work:

```
for i = 1:5  
  mean_ch(i) = mean(ch(i));  
end
```

I know this code is wrong but it conveys the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to end up with 5 separate variables that are named by the loop or a cell array with all 5 variables within it allowing for easy recall. I know there must be a way to write this code I'm just not sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a few options for how you can do this:

- You can put all your channel data into one large matrix first, then compute the mean of the rows or columns using the function [MEAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/mean.html). For example, if each `chX` variable is an N-by-1 array, you can do the following:

  ```
  chArray = [ch1 ch2 ch3 ch4 ch5];  %# Make an N-by-5 matrix
  meanArray = mean(chArray);        %# Take the mean of each column
  ```
- You can put all your channel data into a cell array first, then compute the mean of each cell using the function [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html):

  ```
  meanArray = cellfun(@mean,{ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5});
  ```

  This would work even if each `chX` array is a different length from one another.
- You can use [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) to generate the separate variables for each channel mean:

  ```
  for iChannel = 1:5
    varName = ['ch' int2str(iChannel)];  %# Create the name string
    eval(['mean_' varName ' = mean(' varName ');']);
  end
  ```

Comment: If you have sets of data like this, arrays/vectors are *the* way to go in Matlab.  Using vector operations will result in significantly faster code (in most cases) over using loops/iterators.

Comment: Thank you for your response it has helped me greatly reduce my coding. The first one did not separate the array as I would have liked but did work. The second one did not work for my MATLAB, @mean seems to cause a problem. The EVAL worked perfectly as I wished, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always exactly 5 channels, you can do

```
ch = {ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5}
for j = 1:5
    mean_ch(j) = mean(ch{j});
end
```

A more complicated way would be

```
for j = 1:nchannels
    mean_ch(j) = eval(['mean(ch' num2str(j) ')']);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from gnovice's answer. You could use structures and dynamic field names to accomplish your task.  First I assume that your channel data variables are all in the format *ch** and are the only variables in your MATLAB workspace. The you could do something like the following

```
%# Move the channel data into a structure with fields ch1, ch2, ....
%# This could be done by saving and reloading the workspace
save('channelData.mat','ch*');
chanData = load('channelData.mat');

%# Next you can then loop through the structure calculating the mean for each channel
flds = fieldnames(chanData); %# get the fieldnames stored in the structure

for i=1:length(flds)
     mean_ch(i) = mean(chanData.(flds{i});
end
```