# MATLAB: How can I use a variables value in another variables name?

Tags: matlab, variables, loops, naming-conventions

I am wondering if this is possible. My code looks like this:

```
indexStop = find(firstinSeq(x,4) ~= ...
                 littledataPassed(y:length(littledataPassed),4), 1, 'first');
for z= 0:(n-1)
   indexProcess = find((littledataPassed(y:y+indexStop-1,6) == 1 & ... 
      littledataPassed(y:y+indexStop-1,2) == firstinSeq(x,2) & ... 
      littledataPassed(y:y+indexStop-1,5) == z), 1, 'first'); 
   if isempty(indexProcess)
      msgLength[n](countmsgLength[n],:)= [firstinSeq(x,:) [0 0 0 0 0 0]];
   else
      msgLength[n](countmsgLength[n],:)= [firstinSeq(x,:) ...
         littledataPassed(y+indexProcess-1,:)];
   end
   countmsgLength[n]= countmsgLength[n] + 1;
end
```

I am hoping to have everywhere that reads `[n]` be switched to the actual value of `n`, such that I could use this to add data to nine different variables in the format `msgLength#`.  I have tried searching tutorials and what not but haven't seen anything on the topic.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab) , but I've added some advice below that is specific to the code you posted above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's almost always better to use arrays or [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) to store data than to create a bunch of variables named `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, etc. For example, you can initialize `msgLength` as a cell array with `n` elements:

```
msgLength = cell(1,n);
```

And you can access cells of `msgLength` using curly braces:

```
msgLength{n} = ...  %# Assign something to cell n
```

Your variable `countmsgLength` can just be a regular numeric array, since it appears to only store `n` values. You would just have to change the square brackets to parentheses (i.e. `[n]` to `(n)`).

**However**, if you *really* want to create `n` separate variables, you will likely end up using the [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) function. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143959/using-matlab-loop-funtion-to-name-calculate-variables) show some examples of how to create variables names using the value of another variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use multiple variables, structure [dynamic fieldnames](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/20/advanced-matlab-dynamic-field-names/) using () notation would be handy. If you enter the following:

```
>> n = 1;
>> data.(sprintf('msgLength%u', n)) = [1 2 3 4];
>> n = 2;
>> data.(sprintf('msgLength%u', n)) = [5 6 7 8];
```

You'll get a structure with two fields:

```
>> data
data = 
   msgLength1: [1 2 3 4]
   msgLength2: [5 6 7 8]
```

Despite this, I second gnovice's suggestion of using an array to store data instead of several variables. You could simply add another dimension to `msgLength` so line 7 becomes:

```
msgLength(n,countmsgLength(n),:)= [firstinSeq(x,:) [0 0 0 0 0 0]];
```