# Matlab- How does you name a new variable based on other variables' values?

Tags: variables, matlab, naming, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab)
>   [MATLAB: How can I use a variables value in another variables name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346178/matlab-how-can-i-use-a-variables-value-in-another-variables-name)

I want to name a variable using values of other variables given in a function.
So, if I have values for an x1,x2 I can make the new variable's name as:

x_(x1's value)_(x2's value) as a name.

I've checked out the eval, num2str, strcat functions, but as of yet I can't make it so that I have a variable with the name above which I can assign a value to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an array instead.

Comment: This sort of thing has been covered a few times before: [Matlab: Using a Variable's value in Another Variables Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346178/matlab-using-a-variables-value-in-another-variables-name), [How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab), [Using MATLAB loop funtion to name calculate variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143959/using-matlab-loop-funtion-to-name-calculate-variables).

Comment: Read this list of bad coding practices by @MatlabDoug, in particular point#1 http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/03/08/top-10-matlab-code-practices-that-make-me-cry/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following FAQ:

- [How can I create variables A1, A2,...,A10 in a loop?](http://www.mit.edu/~pwb/cssm/matlab-faq_4.html#evalcell)

It answers the "how" part of your question and recommends a better approach using arrays.

Comment: I don't want to use an array.

Comment: @max: Do you have a good reason for not using arrays, or are you just hellbent on using a bad solution?

Answer (score 2):

As [Jonas suggests](http://#3884786), if `x1` and `x2` are numbers this works:

```
x1 = 3;
x2 = 4;
newValue = 25;

eval(sprintf('x_%i_%i = newValue;',x1,x2));
```

If `x1` and `x2` are strings, this becomes:

```
x1 = 'foo';
x2 = 'bar';
newValue = 25;

eval(sprintf('x_%s_%s = newValue;',x1,x2));
```

or more simply (using concatenation instead of SPRINTF):

```
x1 = 'foo';
x2 = 'bar';
newValue = 25;

eval(['x_' x1 '_' x2 ' = newValue']);
```

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but this probably isn't the best way to go about it. [EVAL should always be avoided.](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1103.html) Creating variables in the using EVAL is (a.k.a. "poofing") is doubly bad.

If you're trying to associate parameters with values, [structures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html) are a much better solution:

```
x1 = 'foo';
x2 = 'bar';
newValue = 25;

x.([x1 '_' x2]) = newValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a really good reason why you'd want to do that (and assuming x1 and x2 have integer values), you can do this by combining [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) and [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html).

```
x1 = 3;
x2 = 4;
newValue = 25;
eval(sprintf('x_%i_%i = newValue;',x1,x2));
```

If x1 and x2 are floats, it'll be trickier since a variable name cannot have dots in it, though it would still be possible as long as you replace the dots with something else.

However, I really have to ask: Are you sure that you want to do that? Because at the moment I cannot imagine an application where would want to create variable names you don't know beforehand, which in turn makes it very hard to write an efficient program.

**EDIT**

There are many useful ways to store your data in arrays. If you really don't want that, you may be interested in accessing data via key/value pairs in a [MAP](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brqqo5e-1.html;jsessionid=JG2hMQ1XRhFXKSbXQQbbnGP92LhRTmKfFTGppBJKcFFQD1GBTWPw!-1666454064), a feature which is available in more recent versions of Matlab. Thus, your key would become `sprintf('%i_%i',x1,x2)`, and the corresponding value would be whatever it is you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dynamic field references.  Loren at the Mathworks gives a writeup here:

[Mathworks: use-dynamic-field-references](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/)