# extracting data from an existing matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix containing 4320 entries

for example:

P=[ 26 29 31 33 35 26 29 ..........25]

I want to create 180 matrices and every matrix contains 24 entries,i.e

the 1st matrix contains the 1st 24 entries

the 2nd matrix contains the 2nd 24 entries and so on

I know a simple method but it will take a long time which is:

P1=P(1:24);P2=P(25:48),..........P180=P(4297:4320)

and it is dificult since I have huge number of entries for

the original matrix P

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and assume this is MATLAB-related, in which case you'd use the `reshape` function:

```
Px = reshape(P, 24, []);
```

`Px` will now be a proper matrix, and you can access each of the 180 "matrices" (actually row vectors, you seem to be confusing the two) by simple MATLAB syntax:

```
P100 = P(:,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the items in the index, counting up, creating a new matrix every 24 entries. Modular arithmetic might help:

```
foreach (var currentIndexInLargerMatrix : int = 0 to 4320)
begin
  matrixToPutItIn := currentIndexInLargerMatrix div 24;
  indexInNewMatrix := currentIndexInLargerMatrix mod 24;
end
```

in many languages the modulus (remainder) operator is either "mod" or "%".
"div" here denotes integer division. Most languages just use the virgule (slash) "/".

This obviously isn't complete code, but should get you started.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to mention that I am using MATLAB program

Answer (score 0):

I think [You's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028640/extracting-data-from-an-existing-matrix/4028757#4028757) is the best way to approach your problem, where each submatrix is stored as a row or column in a larger matrix and is retrieved by simply indexing into that larger matrix.

However, if you really want/need to create 180 separate variables labeled `P1` through `P180`, the way to do this has been discussed in other questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143959/using-matlab-loop-funtion-to-name-calculate-variables). In your case, you could use the function [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) like so:

```
for iMatrix = 1:180                          %# Loop 180 times
  tempP = P((1:24)+24*(iMatrix-1));          %# Get your submatrix
  eval(['P' int2str(iMatrix) ' = tempP;']);  %# Create a new variable
end
```