# How can I use a variable to create MATLAB elements?

Tags: matlab, variables

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab)
>   [MATLAB: How can I use a variables value in another variables name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346178/matlab-how-can-i-use-a-variables-value-in-another-variables-name)

I have the following code:

```
x = textread('/home/data/data.txt','%s')
for i=1:50
    S=load(['/home/data/',x{i},'_file.mat'])
    info_',x{i},' = strcat(S.info1, S.info2)
end
```

Of course, the last line (`info_',x{i},' = strcat(S.info1, S.info2)`) doesn't work. It just doesn't seem to be possible to use a variable to create MATLAB elements. Is this right or am I just doing something wrong here? Is there an elegant workaround?

Comment: Wow, looks like one of those hyper-duplicates: [How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635), [Using MATLAB loop funtion to name calculate variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143959), [Matlab: Using a Variable's value in Another Variables Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346178), [Matlab- How does you name a new variable based on other variables' values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884752)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like

```
eval( sprintf( 'info_%s = strcat( S.info1, S.info2 );', x{i} ) );
```

?

If so, could I discourage you from doing so, see: http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F

Comment: great man, that is exactly what I was looking for. However, I don't see why I shouldn't do it this way.

Comment: so now there seems only one problem left. After using the above command I receive 50 elements, which I would now like to put into one dataset array. I checked out the help for dataset() but couldn't figure it out. If there is no way to address the 50 elements concretely it would suffice if I could just put all my workspace elements into the dataset but I couldn't find an option for that either.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
eval(['info_x{' num2str(i) '}=strcat(S.info1, S.info2)']);
```

Comment: thanks for helping but this unfortunately doesn't work. You should know that x{i} returns a string. Basically I want to name each element 1:50 by this respective string.