# Create 'n' matrices in a loop

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809635/how-to-concatenate-a-number-to-a-variable-name-in-matlab)

Hi everyone, as the title, i'd like to learn if anyone knows how, in Matlab, create 'n' matrices in a loop.

Like this:

```
for (i=1:n)

p_i = P(i, :);
q_i = Q(i, :);

A_i = [p_i, p_i', q_i];
end
```

Matlab, of course, rewrites n times on the matrix A_i, but i would like to have n matrices of 'i' index.

Thank you in advance, have a good day!!

Comment: Duplicates: [How to concatenate a number to a variable name in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2809635/52738), [Matlab: Using a Variable's value in Another Variables Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3346178/52738), [Using MATLAB loop funtion to name calculate variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3143959/52738), [Matlab- How does you name a new variable based on other variables' values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3884752/52738)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could concatenate everything into a 3D array:

```
A_i = zeros(D1,D2,n);  % D1 and D2 are the dimensions of the 2D arrays
for i = 1:n
    p_i = P(i,:);
    q_i = Q(i,:);
    A_i(:,:,i) = [p_i, p_i', q_i];
end
```

If you genuinely want `n` distinct matrices, then you will need a [*cell array*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html).  Your code would become something like:

```
A_i = cell(1,n);
for i = 1:n
    p_i = P(i,:);
    q_i = Q(i,:);
    A_i{i} = [p_i, p_i', q_i];
end
```

Note that you should carefully consider which would suit your needs the best.  The only real advantage of a cell array is that it allows each element to be a different data-type, or a different-sized array.  A 3D array has several advantages over a cell array of 2D arrays (you can sum over it, reshape it, slice 3D sub-chunks out of it, etc. etc.).