# How can I create variables Ai in loop in scilab, where i=1..10

Tags: loops, scilab

I'm using scilab. Basically i want the same as this guy [Create 'n' matrices in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108040/create-n-matrices-in-a-loop)
or this guy http://www.mit.edu/~pwb/cssm/matlab-faq_4.html#evalcell

The answer is not working in scilab, and I can not manage it to do the same in scilab. Can someone help me.

Comment: You should give us an example so we can see what is not working. Code would be fine ;-)

Comment: Does the solution below works for you?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your intention right, you want to use dynamic variable names (=variable names are not hardcoded but generated during execution). Is that correct?

As others already pointed out in the linked posts (and at many other places, e.g. [here](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F)), in general it is not advisable to do this. It's better to use vectors or matrices (2D or 3D), if your variables have the same size and type, e.g. if

```
A1=[1,2];
A2=[3,4];
```

Better way:

```
A(1,1:2)=[1,2];
A(2,1:2)=[3,4];
```

This way you can store the variables in a more efficient matrix form, which executes faster (loops are slow!) and generally more flexible as independent variables (you can define a certain subset of them, and execute matrix operations, etc.)

However if you really want to do it, use `execstr`:

```
clear;  //clear all variables
for i=1:10
  execstr("A"+string(i)+"=[]");   //initialize Ai as empty matrix
  execstr("B"+string(i)+"=0");    //initialize Bi as 0
  execstr("C"+string(i)+"=zeros(2,3)");   //initialize Ci as 2*3 zero matrix
  execstr("D"+string(i)+"=1:i");   //initialize Di as different length vectors
end
disp(A1,"A1");
disp(B2,"B2");
disp(C3,"C3");
disp(D1,"D1");
disp(D5,"D5");
```

If variable names are only important when you display the results, you can make the indices to appear as part of the variable name, e.g.:

```
E=0.1:2:8.1;      //vector with 4 elements
disp(E,"E");
for j=1:4
  mprintf("\nE%i = %.1f",j,E(j));  //appears as 4 different variables on the screen

end
```