# how to access string declared variables in scilab

Tags: scilab

I am having trouble with is line "P_dot_ij_om_+ii(i,1)=P_dot_ij(k,2);"
basically I have declared matrix P_dot_ij_om_1=[] from 1 to i
and in the next line.

I would like to input data e.g. P_dot_ij_om_+ii(i,1)=P_dot_ij(k,2); 
where ii is a number. what is the right expression.

---

```
rows=round(k/360);
i=1;
ii=1;
k=1;
while ii <= rows

     Pdot_names(ii,1)=string("P_dot_ij_om_"+ string(ii));

     disp(Pdot_names(ii))
     execstr(Pdot_names(ii)+'=[]');         // declare indexed matrix

     while i<361

        P_dot_ij_om_+ii(i,1)=P_dot_ij(k,2);
        // P_dot_ij_om_+ii(i,2)=P_dot_ij(k,3);

         disp(k)
         k=k+1;
         i=i+1;
     end
ii=ii+1;


end
```

---

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you got the right answer for your question, please don't forget to 'Accept' it.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works, but in general it is not advised to create string variables. There are much faster and also easier to implement alternatives, see e.g. this thread: [How can I create variables Ai in loop in scilab, where i=1..10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482073/how-can-i-create-variables-ai-in-loop-in-scilab-where-i-1-10/32488300#32488300)

```
rows = 2;
P_dot_ij = [10,20,30;11,21,31;12,22,32];
i=1;
ii=1;
k=1;
while ii <= rows

    //Pdot_names(ii,1)=string("P_dot_ij_om_"+ string(ii));    The firs 'string' is unnecessary
    Pdot_names(ii,1)="P_dot_ij_om_"+string(ii);    

    disp(Pdot_names(ii))
    execstr(Pdot_names(ii)+'=[]');         // declare indexed matrix

    while i<4

        //P_dot_ij_om_+ii(i,1)=P_dot_ij(k,2);
        execstr("P_dot_ij_om_"+string(ii)+"("+string(i)+",1)=P_dot_ij("+string(k)+",2)");           // P_dot_ij_om_+ii(i,2)=P_dot_ij(k,3);
        execstr("P_dot_ij_om_"+string(ii)+"("+string(i)+",2)=P_dot_ij("+string(k)+",3)");

        disp(k)
        k=k+1;
        i=i+1;
    end
    ii=ii+1;
end

disp(P_dot_ij_om_1,"P_dot_ij_om_1");
disp(P_dot_ij_om_1,"P_dot_ij_om_2");
```

And also next time please post selfcontained code examples, because otherwise I can only guess what is `k` and `P_dot_ij`.